# Hugging Face Transformer multiprocessing training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to train NER using distilbert on CPU. However, training is slow. Is there any way to do some CPU optimization to reduce the training time?

Comment: Is your CPU actually only showing one active core during training? PyTorch should already be optimized for multicore execution, which is why I'm surprised. Most single-core execution time is likely from other parts of the code... Please include an [mcve] of code that is severely lacking in performance and exhibits restriction to a single core.